# Rails - How to permanently randomize IDs of a database table (Postgres)

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a list of profiles in my database and I would like to permanently randomize them, so they are in a random order. I do not want to merely randomize a query of the database. Does anyone know how to do this using rails and postgres?

Comment: Is `default_scope { order('RANDOM') }` an option? See [`default_scope`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods.html#method-i-default_scope)

Comment: Why? It doesn't sound reasonable at all.

Comment: I agree with @JakubKania : Database rows are not made to be sorted, or randomized. If you want a randomized result, make a query that fetch your datas, THEN randomize your result.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Why do you think you can't you do this with a query?

Comment: I wanted to create a program that runs every day and uses a randomized set of data. I only wanted to randomize the set once and use the same set over and over again, but I guess randomizing it each time through a query would also work.